# Embed PDF will randomly not display

Tags: html, firefox, pdf, google-chrome, adobe

We are displaying an inline PDF via an object tag:

```
<object data='myPDF.pdf' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%'></object>
```

On most loads, this works just fine - the browser will display the PDF using adobe's browser plugin-in. However, sometimes the browser will not display the PDF - it will load either a transparent or blank white background with no content inside it. This is occuring in both Firefox and Chrome browser. IE does not seem have this issue.

Even more bizarre - after the issue occurs, if we resize or move the browser, the PDF magically re-appears.

Has this ever happened to anyone else? Any ideas on how to improve this performance?

Comment: +1 because I've encountered this too, but it's so rare I mostly just ignored it. Hope you get a solution!

Comment: still occurring 10 years later

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with Adobe, I've encountered it too but never found a solution. It doesn't matter wich browser I use or wich computer. It just happens some times...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I've just had a similar problem and couldn't find a solution online.

I discovered some of my pdf's had a capitalised extension (.PDF), once I lower-cased them all it works fine for both in iframe and embed.